# Tightly coupled limit of the Boltzmann equation

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

When i have studied anisotropic of CMB, I couldn’t understand some technical things if you could help me. I appreciate it.
What i couldn’t understand is:
When we study tightly coupling limit of the Boltzman equation which is:

$\frac{d\Theta}{d\eta}+ik\mu\Theta=-\frac{d\Phi}{d\eta}-ik\mu\Psi-\frac{d\tau}{d\mu}\left[\Theta_0-\Theta+\mu u_b-\frac{1}{2}P_2(\mu)\prod_{}^{} \right]$

we have to ignore multipoles ($l\lt 2$). That is we have to multiply ($\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}p_{0}d\mu $)

We get

$\frac{d\Theta_0}{d\eta}+k\Theta_1=-\frac{d\Psi}{d\eta}$ ——-(1)

Getting this equation is straightforward but I don’t know why we ignored or setted other terms equal to zero such as the first and second term of Boltzman equation inside the bracket (the third and fourth also known that would be zero.

Thanks.